# How to decide which features are important in this binary classification task?

Tags: classification, binary-data, unbalanced-classes, feature-engineering, auc

Consider a binary classification problem, where the dataset is highly imbalanced, with only around 20% positive labels and 80% negative labels.

Feature A has higher AuROC when considering all the data, but Feature B has higher AuROC if we compute simply using equal no. of positive and negative labeled data.

Which feature would be more important and why? On one hand, feature A has a high AuROC for a distribution closer to test data, but on the other hand, suppose we are more interested in positive label predictions, is feature B more essential?

I'm lacking a theoretically justified explanation for this scenario. What is the recommended approach in the real world?